# PyQt: How to create a simple information at programm-start that shutdown automatically

Tags: python, pyqt, messagebox

for a pyqt-program I want to create a simple information message for the program-start. The key is, that it should disappear automatically after a few seconds.

I tried to use a singleshot, but it didn't work:

```
class MainProgramm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        QTimer.singleShot(60, self.EntryMessage) 
...

def EntryMessage(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "About","text")
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you right, it seems like [QSplashScreen](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsplashscreen.html) is what you need. It's actually a part of Qt, so you can use it without any limitations.

Comment: It's an idea. But QSplashScreen is for pictures and I'm trying to include text to it (which differs from a certain value) and fail.

Comment: @JamesMitch `QSplashScreen` has a `showMessage` method that allows you to show text on it.